# Referring to local ID in the context of a <BASE> tag (SVG on Firefox)

Tags: html, svg

My problem happens on a current Firefox on Win7 using SVG (this might not be too relevant to the actual problem):

`

```
<head>  
<!-- base href="http://127.0.0.1/package/index.php" /-->  
</head>  

<body>  

<svg height="150px" width="400px">  

<defs>  
<linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">  
<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(120,120,120);stop-opacity:1" />  
<stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(40,40,40);stop-opacity:1" />  
</linearGradient>  
</defs>

<rect x="225" y="30" width="80" height="28" fill="url(#grad1)"/>  
</svg>  
</body>  
</html>
```

`
The gradient is identified by the ID (grad1) and referred to by the rect-tag. This works fine as long as the base-tag is commented out as above. As soon as the base-tag is set free, my pretty rectangle disappears; presumably because the ID is appended to the URL defined in the base tag. When that happens, Firefox appears to make an extra round trip to the server.

My problem is, this page in kept in a package that sometimes includes the base-tag and sometimes does not. I appear not to have much control over that without modifying that other software (which I do not want to do) So my question is: how can I "anchor" the references to the ID's in the local file, so that they become independent of the presence of the base-tag ?

Answer (score 2):

If your `<base>` element refers to an other page, then FF behavior is the correct one.

Relative `<funcIRI>` should be read as `url(<currentURI>#element)`.
The `<base>` element does change the `currentURI` of the document to the one set in its `href` attribute.

So a possible solution, if you have access to the svg markup, is to use an absolute path in the `<funcIRI>` : `url(://path/to/your/page.php#element)`.
This way, the base element won't have any influence on the `<funcIRI>` you do use.

Also, you may have an issue if the `cache-control` header of the php response is set to `no-cache`, this may make the browser to always send a new request to the server.